# Switch or Foreach to replace a series of if - else statements?

Tags: php, post, foreach, switch-statement

I am confused on which to use, or if I should use both. I have an array of post data, and want to first check if each `$_POST['data']` is empty, and then if it is empty, set a variable $data to some value from my database. If it is not empty then I want to set `$data = $_POST['data']`.

I know I can use a series of if statements, but seriously there has to be a more efficient way. I considered switching `$_POST[$key]` but does the switch know that I am talking about the `$key` and not the `$_POST`? I am going to test this but I would like to know what the best practices are in this area.

For reference, I am making an update staff data app for my company. If the user fills in a form area, then I want the new data to go into my `$update_data` array, but if the user leaves the form area empty, I want those inputs to be set to their current values, so they do not get erased from the database.

-- Edit --

So I just realized that using a switch might mean even more code, because I would have to write the if statements anyway. Foreach??

-- Edit --

```
if (empty($_POST) === false && empty($errors) === true) {
    if (empty($_POST['name']) === false) {
        $staff_name = $_POST['name'];
    } else {
        $staff_name = staff_data($staff_id, 'name', $_POST['language']);
    }

    if (empty($_POST['title']) === false) {
        $title = $_POST['title'];
    } else {
        $title = staff_data($staff_id, 'title', $_POST['language']);
    }

    if (empty($_POST['email']) === false) {
        $email = $_POST['email'];
    } else {
        $email = staff_data($staff_id, 'email', $_POST['language']);
    }

    // ... You get it a lot of if statements one for each array key below:

    $staff_data = array(
            'name'          => $staff_name,
            'title'         => $title,
            'email'         => $email,
            'phone'         => $phone,
            'quote'         => $quote,
            'specialty'     => $specialty,
            'bio'           => $bio,
            'path'          => $path,
            'language_id'   => $_POST['language']
        );

        if(staff_exists($staff_id, $_POST['language']) === true) {
            change_staff($staff_id, $staff_data, $_POST['language']);
        } else {
            insert_staff($staff_id, $staff_data);
        }
```

Comment: Can we see your current code?

Comment: Yes, I just posted the relevant part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `switch` statement will essentially let you test against a variable's value and perform some function if the value matched the specified value. Here is an example:

```
$favcolor="red";
switch ($favcolor) // switch will test for various values against variable $favcolor
{
    case "red":  // If value of $favcolor equals `red`
      echo "Your favorite color is red!"; // then this code will be executed
      break;
    case "blue": // if value of $favcolor equals `blue`
      echo "Your favorite color is blue!"; // then this code will be executed
      break;
    case "green":
      echo "Your favorite color is green!";
      break;
    default: // if value of $favcolor does not equal `red`, `blue` or `green`
      echo "Your favorite color is neither red, blue, or green!"; // then this code will be executed
}
```

On the other hand a `foreach` loop serves a very different purpose. It is usually used to iterate over a group of values (array) and execute a particular piece of code for each of the value.

```
foreach ($array as $value)
{ 
   // you may check the value to match something but its not required
   if($value === "NINJA") {
      echo "You are about to die!";
   } else {
      echo "You are Lucky!";
   }
}
```

Or you can simply run a foreach loop without checking for any values and executing a specific piece of code for each of the values like so:

```
foreach ($array as $value)
{ 
   //code to be executed;
}
```

When to use what?

Use `foreach` if you just want to loop over an array and perform a function for each of its values

Use `switch` if you want to test a specific variable against various values and perform a function based on the value.

a switch statement can be used inside a foreach loop too, in fact its doing so is useful in variety of cases. So if i re-write an above mentioned function using both foreach and switch it will look something like:

```
foreach ($array as $value)
{ 
   switch ($value)
   {
      case "NINJA" :
          echo "You are about to die!";
          break;
      default :
          echo "You are Lucky!";
   }
}
```

But generally you would want to use the switch statement if you want to test again multiple values and not just a couple of them. It makes your code more readable and easy to manage.